# python3 how do i convert my string into a list then count the number of occurrences of a character I'm searching for?

Tags: python, string, list, count

I have this so far:

```
def char_count(string, search):
    newList = list(string)
    return newList.count(search)
```

When I run it, I get:

> TypeError: list() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

This is bizarre to me because I thought the list function DOES take a parameter?
What's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Provide the full traceback. Could be you've shadowed `list` somewhere.

Comment: Since strings already have a count method, I don't see the point in converting it to a list.

Answer (score 3):

The `list` constructor can indeed take one positional argument (an iterable like a string). I guess, you shadowed the name `'list'` somewhere in your code. You should avoid naming your variables like built-ins (`int`, `list`, etc.) or commonly used modules (e.g. `string`).

Why don't you use the string's `count()` method anyway:

```
return string.count(search)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, just wondering, what does shadowing mean?

Comment: If you declare a variable like: `list = []`, the name `'list'` now refers to your variable, and no longer to the built-in type `list`. Your `list` is shadowing good ole Python's `list`.